# Better Compatible version of Hl7, v2 or v3?

Tags: hl7-v2, hl7-v3

I am going to implement a generic HMIS with true implementation of HL7. I have studied all the advantages and disadvantages of both versions of HL7 i.e v2 and v3. But still the confusion exists that which version is better to go with implementation either it is v2 for its stability or v3 for its plug and play compatibility. Need your opinion.

Comment: How is this Java-se, Spring or JSF related? And an upvote within 24 minutes?

Comment: @Kukeltje Java  is related because most of the implementation of hl7 has been done in Java and java developer can answer it most rightly

Comment: How can Java developers better answer questions about stability then just people who know the standard best? Secondly, SO is not for 'opinions', but for answers to actual coding problems or very closely related. So If you have a code example where you

Comment: @Kukeltje Giving opinion is also a kind of help of beginners by professionals and SO is definitely a platform where beginners can clear their concepts by getting help. A programmer knows the problems  that one faced during implementation of anything. If a java developer here worked in v2 and v3 , he/she better do the comparison of both by reminding the problems he/she faced. If you can't getting my point and can't help kindly leave because its better to stay quite rather than degrading others. Thanks

Comment: Giving opinions is indeed helping, but that is **not** what stackOverflow is for. And I'm not degrading anyone, I'm merely stating that questions like this do not belong in StackOverflow. The problem here is that the approach 1 developer took can be different from the approach another developer took and hence they can come to different conclusions. Getting into a discussion about this is not what SO is for.

Answer (score 0):

The HL7 is the organization but also is a set of interoperability standards. It means it is not a function in your system that operates on its own, it is a way that your system communicates with other systems. So the interface that you need to implement in your system - HL7v2 or HL7v3 or HL7 FHIR – is actually dictated by your counterparts.

For example, if you are in US, most likely you'll end up with HL7v2 for messaging, HL7v3 CDA for documents (better know as a separate C-CDA standard) and HL7 FHIR for SMART initiatives. (Let's assume we are not talking about IHE profiles with "v3" suffix.) For Canada and UK it will be the same with the only difference that these countries are using HL7v2 and HL7v3 for *messaging*.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer your question based on Implementation and Data consumption.

HL7v2 is pipe delimited and v3 is of XML, FHIR comes in JSON and XML  flavors. Before discussing advantage and disadvantage,  it is essential to understand how the end system consumes data. What provision they have, and based on that you can proceed further.

If  this question is regarding how efficiently all patient data can be captured in a message format? . I will go with both V2 and V3. V3 is much more standardized, gives more specifications and descriptions. V2 is also has HL7 specific standards for it, if you think that specific message format of yours (ADT/ORU/DFT) lacks specific features to capture, you can use Z-segment or NTE. V3 CDA standards makes sure (upto what I have used), covers most information with its specification itself.

For (Eg:consider CDA standards) Based on the needs CDA can come with its own flavor, as of HL7 standards there are separate Progress notes C-CDA, Procedure notes C-CDA, Transition of Care C-CDA, Diagnostic Imaging Report C-CDA and so on.